# Error compiling Djinni under windows

Tags: windows, scala, makefile, cygwin, djinni

I am trying to compile Dropbox's Djinni, under windows using cygwin to try:
https://github.com/dropbox/djinni

What is causing this error even though sbt-launch.jar is there under the right folder.

```
$ make
./example/run_djinni.sh
Building Djinni...
Error: Unable to access jarfile /cygdrive/c/users/vlama/dropboxcode/djinni/djinni-master/src/support/sbt-launch.jar
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'build_ios/example/libtextsort.xcodeproj' failed
make: *** [build_ios/example/libtextsort.xcodeproj] Error 1
```

I want to make Djinni in cygwin first to try things out and then finallly natively make it for windows, so how would one go about doing that because the instructions in the github is mainly targeted for linux users.

Comment: You might try running `bash -x ./example/run_djinni.sh` to see what command printed the `Error: Unable to access jarfile` line.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that java on windows doesn't accept linux path seprator '**/**', so you have to convert the paths that are passed to java by djinni build scripts to windows format.

The files run_djinni.sh and ./src/support/sbt  are where you'll have to take care of this. Personally I used cygwin to run the build scripts and modified the paths being passed to java in stated files by using cygpath -pw to convert the paths to windows format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) or [Git](https://git-scm.com/).

That is you will get "sh.exe".

It works on windows quite well.

Don't forget a path to the System Path:

System / Advanced System Settings / Enviroment Variables.

For MINGW: MINGW\bin

For Git: Git\bin

Link: [djinni windows](https://gist.github.com/vmaks/bc09aa226272eb5f810e)